# How to connect my custom domain to github.io

Tags: domains, dns, cname, github, jekyll

What should I do to see my `github.io` page content when I enter `mydomain.com` into browser address bar?

I have a custom .com domain and a Jekyll generated webpage at `username.github.io/repositoryname`. Github [tells me](https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working/) to set a CNAME record in my repository pointing to my custom domain and if it didn't work add an *A* or *CNAME* record in my domain DNS settings. Simply I can't get it to work. Which records should I change in my DNS provider exactly?

And one last point, I prefer to see the content from github project and not to be forwarded to it's URL (I prefer users don't notice that I am using github.io).

Any insights?

Answer (score 2):

I see the question is rather old, but anyway,

1. The name of your repository should be "username.github.io", not "repositoryname"
2. Github documentation you want to follow step by step to get this working is

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain

Github will set the CNAME record in your repository for you, as you go through the steps in the documentation.

There are 4 IPv4 and 4 IPv6 github IP addresses to configure at your DNS provider for apex domain (mydomain.com) those are configured by A and AAAA records. You can configure all 8, but one of each will be enough.

Comment: It's probably courteous to GitHub to set up all 8 records, since 8 are given. And there is a slight redundancy benefit since if one IP goes down, browsers [will eventually retry one of the others](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/12704/54214).

Answer (score 1):

It requires two things;

1. Add a file called `CNAME` at the root of the project which only contains the domain name, see [the docs](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/)
2. In your DNS server, add an entry. This is done at your domain name service provider, or named/bind zone file

Follow the instructions [on setting up a custom domain with GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/)

Comment: I have already read those pages and my problem is not solved yet.